# Favicon is identical to Islam's

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The favicon for this site and [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/) are essentially identical. Both say 'is'. Can we change this one so that it's not hopelessly confusing?

The Interpersonal Skills one:

[image]

Islam:

[image]

Comment: I say InterPersonal Skills. Or IPS.

Comment: They took from first name and last name. Inter <personal> Skills

Comment: Looks like a lowercase i to me and an uppercase S

Comment: @Catija A lowercase i which even without the dot is as tall as a capital letter? Looks more like a Turkish capital dotted i.

Comment: Yes, that was my fault. I will get this updated as soon as I can snag some designer time. I'll make sure it's fixed before going public or much sooner.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Maybe Islam can get [moon and star](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRkHFKowZF5kvZQatAJ-9BWTSoVAYxalRenzS_kd9eo2hmyr4NkPTefVw) favicon.

Comment: @RobertCartaino any updates? (Or is the site not going to make it and so it's not worth it?)

Comment: Mithrandir, I was holding off for further discussion, but someone should be fixing it before the site launches. Stand by.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Should I make a bug report for Brian Nickel that the iOS App icon is still the old one (iS) or is this something that will fix itself eventually? We had the same issue on ELL for a long time and I think the avatar artwork had to be manually updated eventually.

Comment: @Catija It will fix itself in 7-ish days.  For whatever reason, the API doesn't return image URLs with the cache breaker from the web, so the layers of caching are: Fastly CDN invalidation (done), 7 days from when it was fetched by the app, and restarting the app (which probably happens at least once per day).  Users who have never loaded the site icon before (most people not in the private beta) will see the new logo now.

Comment: Thanks @BrianNickel for that very helpful information! I'm glad to know that any new users will see the updated icon!

Answer (score 7):

I am not the greatest at graphic design, but here's an icon concept:

[image: Proposed icon]

I hereby release this into the public domain. If someone can improve it, please do; here's the SVG: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8205354/Interpersonal%20StackExchange%20Icon.svg

Comment: They don't generally do custom artwork until a site graduates. There are a couple of exceptions but they're rare.

Comment: I know we don't need it yet, but I really like this concept. Well done and thanks

Comment: Even the site which got favicon in beta stage didn't got the colorful one except craftcms.